# Jquery variable scope issues

Tags: jquery

I'm having issues with variable scope in jquery I think. The variable I call `refid` below is returning the valid value in the initial alert in the higher-level function... "like69" is my expected value.

However down in the success function, it is not working properly. I want it to return the same "like69", but instead in the lower-level alert, it is giving me "success". On the `.switchClass` line, its not working and throwing an undefined error.

Any tips on where I'm going wrong... how to make this value flow through?

```
$(".ajax-like").submit(function(){
  alert("Initial part going...");
  var refid = $(this).find('input[name="refid"]').val();
  alert(refid);
  var data = {
    "action": "like"
  };
  data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "galleryajax.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
    data: data,
    success: function(data, refid) {
      alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
      alert(refid);
      $('#'+refid).switchClass("thumb-comment", "thumb-comment2", 1000);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Could just pass `context: document.getElementById(refid),` to your `$.ajax` and use `$(this)` within the success callback.

Comment: Sorry that's a bit over my head... are you saying to replace ('#'+refid) with (document.getElementById(refid)) ? I get the feeling what you're proposing requires more than just that? :)

Comment: No, I'm saying just add another parameter to your `$.ajax` options (context above) then, within the success function, instead of `$('#'+refid)` use `$(this)`

Comment: Gotcha, clear, giving it a go.

Comment: This is drivin me nuts :(  I'm still getting undefined, can you you pls try it? http://beta.runic-paradise.com/gallery.php - click the heart icon on top/left thumbnail. It gives an undefined error in console

Comment: You don't have jQuery UI loaded. [`.switchClass`](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/) is part of jquery-UI not regular jQuery.

Comment: adding    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> and retrying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop that variable's mentioning from AJAX response handler:

```
success: function(data) {
   alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
   alert(refid);
   $('#'+refid).switchClass("thumb-comment", "thumb-comment2", 1000);
}
```

... as it's already in the handlers' scope (`refid` variable is defined in the outer function).

What happens is following: the function specified in `success` property of `$.ajax` options object will be called with three arguments:

- `data` (the response)
- `textStatus` (string description of the response's status)
- `jqXHR` (promise-like AJAX object)

You describe the handler as a function getting two arguments instead, but that's quite fine in JS. The problem is, you declare `refid` as the function parameter - and with this, you essentially create a new variable (name binding, to be precise) named `refid` in the `success` scope. That variable will shadow the outer one. That's why you get `'success'` string displayed in alert.

Comment: You mean don't declare it as a parameter of the response handler. Obviously it can't be dropped from the handler entirely because it's used within the handler...

Comment: I've done this now... and the value flows through properly, thank you. But I'm still not getting the intended result -- I still get an undefined error, even though I can see in my source I have a <span id="like69">  ...  why can't jquery see this to execute.switchClass()  ?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the class on the span and in my source it shows:   <span class="thumb-comment" id="like69">
   <form class="ajax-like" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
     <input type="hidden" name="mcname" value="rune" placeholder="Favorite restaurant" />
     <input type="hidden" name="galleryid" value="69" placeholder="Favorite beverage" />
     <input type="hidden" name="refid" value="like69" />
    <button type="submit" style="border: 0; background: none;">
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
    0
    </button>
    </form>
   </span>

Comment: Well, you actually target the element correctly; it's `switchClass` method missing from the object. That's because the method belongs to jQuery UI API ([source](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/)), and not jQuery.

Comment: Accepting raina's answer because it came first to solve what I initially asked, although Brad's supplied the secondary answer before Raina's edit later. Not sure how to approach this technicality fairly... so upvoting Brad's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Second option: Use the `context` parameter of `$.ajax` and supply the element to the callback function. e.g. (note `//!!` comments below)

```
$(".ajax-like").submit(function(){
  alert("Initial part going...");
  var refid = $(this).find('input[name="refid"]').val();
  alert(refid);
  var data = {
    "action": "like"
  };
  data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "galleryajax.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
    context: document.getElementById(refid), //!! ADD THIS
    data: data,
    success: function(data) { //!! REMOVE refid FROM HERE
      alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
      //!!alert(refid)
      //!!$('#'+refid).switchClass("thumb-comment", "thumb-comment2", 1000);
      //!! USE $(this) INSTEAD
      $(this).switchClass("thumb-comment", "thumb-comment2", 1000);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```